# Re installing Chrome and Flash player

Tags: flash, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I am having terrible problems with youtube and other sites.
I think I need to replace my Chrome OS and Shock wave.

`~/.config/google-chrome/Default` the location of my chrome files - I have no idea how to find this or what to do with it.

`/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` - my flash player, the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall Chrome but not through software centre...

Go to the following post and follow the procedure i've described in the answer "BETTER WAY TO DO IT-"

[Installed 11.10 Help! cannot find chrome after install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114488/installed-11-10-help-cannot-find-chrome-after-install/136871#136871)