# Chrome Removal and replacement

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re installing Chrome and Flash player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136985/re-installing-chrome-and-flash-player)

~/.config/google-chrome/Default I am not able to find this location. I need to re install chrome as I am having problems with it.

Please advise me on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've just answer your question in a a question similar to this some time ago...

Heres a link to it...

[Re installing Chrome and Flash player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136985/re-installing-chrome-and-flash-player)